# I’m going to Portugal from Latvia and my flight has a layover in Dublin, Ireland. Do I need a transit visa in Ireland?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, schengen-visas, ireland

I’m going to Portugal from Latvia and my flight has a layover in Dublin, Ireland. Do I need a transit visa in Ireland ? Or I can stay in transit zone in Ireland ?
Please help me to for this.
I’m going to book ticket so please help me as soon as possible

Comment: Without **Citizenship** information,  this question cannot be answered properly. Ireland is not part of the Schengen area.

Comment: I have student visa in Latvia. Latvia is a schengan country

Comment: But Ireland, where you may need a visa -  depending on your citizenship ,  is not.

Comment: I just changing my plane not to enter Ireland

Comment: It does't matter, your citizenship determines if you need a transit visa. With the transit visa you are not **allowed** to leave the airport, only to change planes.

Answer (score 2):

Informationen about [Irish Transit visa](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas) and conditions with list of citizenships that need it as well as fees.